# Single AppSession can't subscribe to and publish on the same topic

Tags: python, autobahn, crossbar

Based on the simple Hello World example, I replace the `oncounter` topic with the `onhello` one when publishing. That would mean the `AppSession` is subscribing to a topic it is itself publishing. I'd guess it should be able to receive its own messages but it looks like it doesn't. Is there a way to do this?

For a reproducible example:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks
```

from autobahn.twisted.util import sleep
from autobahn.twisted.wamp import ApplicationSession

class AppSession(ApplicationSession):

```
@inlineCallbacks
def onJoin(self, details):

    def onhello(msg):
        print("event for 'onhello' received: {}".format(msg))
    sub = yield self.subscribe(onhello, 'com.example.onhello')

    counter = 0
    while True:

        yield self.publish('com.example.onhello', counter)
        print("published to 'onhello' with counter {}".format(counter))
        counter += 1

        yield sleep(1)
```

After running `crossbar start`, I see the `onhello` topic being published, but it is not received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is, that - by default - a publisher does not get an event published even if the publisher is itself subscribed to the topic published to.

You can alter that behavior by provided an `options` argument to `publish()`:

```
yield self.publish('com.example.onhello', counter,
   options = autobahn.wamp.types.PublishOptions(excludeMe = False))
```

Comment: Ok I see, it was not obvious... That makes sense now, thanks!